# Casbah scala nested document print

Tags: scala, casbah

I am new to Casbah and scala. How can i access nested document in scala? I have few fields defined here and as you can see Currency and Ratios are nested document. When I am trying to print Currency.ExchangeCCY it gives me an error. How can i get specific value value rather than whole of nested object?

```
val query = MongoDBObject("RunDate" -> "18-02-2015")                      
val fields = MongoDBObject("Currency.ExchangeCCY" -> 1,         
                           "Currency.MarketCapCCY" -> 1)

for (d <- price.find(query,fields))  println(d("Currency"))
//> { "ExchangeCCY" : "CAD" , "MarketCapCCY" : "CAD"}
//| { "ExchangeCCY" : "CAD" , "MarketCapCCY" : "CAD"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access a sub-document using `d.getAs[DBObject]` or `d.getAsOrElse[DBObject]`. This returns another `DBObject`, from which you can query the specific field.

In your case, ignoring error handling for now,

```
val currencyDocument = d.getAs[DBObject]("Currency").get
val exchangeCcy = currencyDocument("ExchangeCCY")
```

There are a couple of problems with this approach. The most glaring one is the compile-time type of `exchangeCcy`. If you look at the [Casbah Scaladocs](http://mongodb.github.io/casbah/api/#com.mongodb.casbah.commons.MongoDBObject), you will see that it has type `AnyRef`. If you think that this should always be a string, you can enforce this with:

```
val exchangeCcy = currencyDocument.getAs[String]("ExchangeCCY").get
```

`exhangeCcy` is now guaranteed to be a string.

What about error handling? What if we can't cast `Currency` to a `DBObject`, or `exhangeCcy` to a String? The clue is in `getAs`. This returns a [Scala option](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option) which is either `Some(value)` or `None` if the cast failed. A fault tolerant way of reading the `Currency` sub-document would therefore be:

```
val currencyDocument = d.getAs[DBObject]("Currency") match {
    case Some(v) => v
    case None => throw new IllegalStateException(
        "Failed to read 'Currency'")
    }
```

Comment: No problem. You might consider reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers . If you accept answers, it will make people more likely to help you in the future.